# How to update all the values of an column with regular expression in Rails 4

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, active-record-query

I have a table with an column "Ip" all has the values like 10.x.x.x, now I want to replace the 10 with 20 of all the records. Is their any way to do this via Activerecord or Do I need to execute only raw postgres query with regexp_replace?

Comment: Both are possible. You could just fire up the `rails console` and execute some code to change the ip addresses. Test in development mode first, of course.

Answer (score 5):

```
ModelName.update_all("column_name = replace(columnname,'originaltext','replacement') ")
```

Eg:

```
Resource.update_all("fqdn = replace(fqdn,'d3p5','d6p6') ")
```

Now all the occurrences of "d3p5" of fqdn column replaced with d6p6